# Kafka Bytes Rejected In Monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

We have 8 nodes kafka cluster and kafka manager installed.

We are monitoring via new relic.

new Relic and kafka manager both are reporting  kafka is rejecting bytes.  I am not able to find the cause.

In broker logs there are no error lines.

JMS BEAN - JMX/kafka.server/BrokerTopicMetrics/BytesRejectedPerSec/OneMinuteRate

[image]
[image]

Kafka Config -

```
auto.create.topics.enable=false
auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true
broker.id=180
controlled.shutdown.enable=true
controlled.shutdown.max.retries=3
default.replication.factor=1
delete.topic.enable=true
kafka.http.metrics.host=0.0.0.0
kafka.http.metrics.port=24042
kafka.log4j.dir=/logs/kafka
kerberos.auth.enable=false
leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds=300
leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage=10
log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size=134217728
log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms=604800000
log.cleaner.enable=true
log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio=0.5
log.cleaner.threads=1
log.dirs=/kafka/data
log.retention.bytes=5368709120
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.retention.hours=72
log.retention.ms=259200000
log.roll.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
message.max.bytes=3145728
min.insync.replicas=1
num.io.threads=8
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=6
offsets.topic.num.partitions=50
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
port=9092
quota.consumer.default=52428800
quota.consumer.default=52428800
quota.producer.default=26214400
quota.producer.default=26214400

replica.fetch.max.bytes=4194304
replica.lag.max.messages=6000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=60000
unclean.leader.election.enable=false
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=6000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper01.prod.***.com:2181,zookeeper02.prod.***.com:2181,zookeeper03.prod.***.com:2181
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT

listeners=PLAINTEXT://kafka01.prod.***.com:9092,
broker.id.generation.enable=false
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
num.network.threads=8
```

Answer (score 0):

By examining Kafka sources ([ref1](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c5ae154a3fdcf20d388405361da37feed0c64ad9/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/Log.scala#L1106), [ref2](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/c5ae154a3fdcf20d388405361da37feed0c64ad9/core/src/main/scala/kafka/log/Log.scala#L1380)), it seems that the only reason counted into **BytesRejectedPerSec** (`bytesRejectedRate`) is the message size exceeding `config.maxMessageSize`.

Note: recompression and message format conversion may also affect the message size beyond what's being sent by the producer.